# How can I combine fields from two objects into one?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following

```
public class AnswerDetail
{
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Correct { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Response { get; set; }
}
```

- From the client I received an AnswerDetail with the Response field
  populated: AnswerDetail rfc
- From the database I received an AnwerDetail with the Correct  field 
  populated: AnswerDetail afd

How can I combine these to make another AnswerDetail object that takes the AnswerId, Text and Correct from afd and the Response from rfc?

Update: Removed ClientAnswers class to simplify question

Comment: How are the two list linked? Is the AsnwerId the same for afd&rfc relative to a questionid?

Comment: Yes the AnswerIds match up. I just removed the other containing class as it complicates the question and I can do that part.

Comment: offtopic but: you know that you can write bool? instead of Nullable<bool> ?

Comment: @gsharp - Thanks and yeah I should and will change that.

Comment: Can't you just create a new object and set the appropriate fields?

Comment: are rfc and aft list or single object

Comment: @Melina I think you should revert the question including the CLientAnswer class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rfc.Select(r=>
    new AnswerDetail
    {
        AnswerId =r.AnswerId,
        Text=r.Text,
        Response=r.Response,
        Correct=afd.Single(c=>c.AnswerId==r.AnswerId).Correct
    }
           );
```

Comment: `Where(...).Single()` should really just be `Single(...)`.

Comment: Thanks - Your answer was I think the first one so I marked as correct. A lot more answers I would like to mark correct but I can only mark one correct so I upvoted the others.

Comment: _AnswerId, Text and Correct from afd_ it says.

Comment: you used the wrong variables, afd should be used for the iteration, rfd for the Single statement

Comment: I'd say projection is unnecessary here, it's less work to just iterate & update like in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new `AnswerDetail`, then simply set the properties from the correct source.

```
AnswerDetail adCombined = new AnswerDetail
{
    AnswerId = afd.AnswerId,
    Text = afd.Text,
    Correct = afd.Correct,
    Response = rfc.Response
};
```

Comment: actually they are single because the OP have edited the question

Comment: @trippino: No, they were single objects before but of a different tpye. It was not clear if the single `ClientAnswers` object contains one or multiple `AnswerDetails` and how they are related. Now the question is clear.

Comment: The OP wanted to create a ClientAnswer which contains a ICollection of AnswerDetails

Answer (score 1):

```
AnswerDetail ans = new AnswerDetail{Correct = rfc.Correct, Response = afd.Response}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybee you can try this:

```
var combined = from rfcItem in rfc.Answers
               join afdItem in afd.Answers on rfcItem.AnswerId equals afdItem.AnswerId
               select new AnswerDetail 
               { 
                   AnswerId = afdItem.AnswerId,
                   Text = afdItem.Text,
                   Correct = afdItem.Correct,
                   Response = rfcItem.Response
               };
```

Answer (score 0):

Well given you already have the `Response` fields from the client, it's really just a case updating the results with the correct answer from the DB e.g.

```
foreach (var a in rfc)
{
    a.Correct = afd.Answers.Single(x => x.AnswerId == a.AnswerId).Select(x => x.Correct);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that there always be the correspondent rfc answer for each afd:

```
var zipped = from rows in afd.Answers
             select new AnswerDetail()
             {
                AnswerId = rows.AnswerId,
                Correct = rows.Correct,
                Response = rfc.Answers.First(r=>r.AnswerId == rows.AnswerId).Response,
                Text = rows.Text
             };
```

You can create your whole ClientAnswer as:

```
var zipped = new ClientAnswers()
             {
                QuestionId = yourQuestionId, 
                Answers = (from rows in afd.Answers
                          select new AnswerDetail()
                          {
                              AnswerId = rows.AnswerId,
                              Correct = rows.Correct,
                              Response = rfc.Answers.First(r => r.AnswerId == rows.AnswerId).Response,
                              Text = rows.Text
                          }).ToList()
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

You information doesn't say about lists.

why not:

```
afd.Response = rfc.Response;
```

Comment: It did, the OP edited the question for simplicity. Check the edit history.